# .NET Core publish appsettings.json

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I've just pulled a VS 2017 RC created solution from a shared repo and I'm trying to run it in my Mac using VS Code. I got the solution built however when I get to run it, then an exception is thrown because it can't find the appsettings.json. I checked the /bin/debug/netcoreapp1.1 folder and it isn't there so I'm assuming that's why.

I have read that in the previous project.json you could use the publishOptions but with this new mechanism of csproj I wasn't able to find anything.
I was also thinking whether I need to change something in the StartUp.cs:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
```

so that I can find a common path for the appsettings.json to be shared across the two worlds (VS 2017 RC and VS Code).

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like you'll need to work with the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" and the 'launchSettings.json' file. Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Answer (score 2):

Adding the actual folder where the `appsetting.json` is located was enough to get this working in the `launch.json`. What I did:

```
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}
```

got amended like this:

```
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/MyASPNETCoreMainProject
```

and got it working